# How to delete only the data in the rows (prevent the rows to be deleted) in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I was trying to delete the data values in the row but it also removes the row in the DataGridView.

code :

**spSumGrid.Sheets[0].Rows.Clear();//It deletes the Data & row in the table**

```
But I want to delete only the data in  the row..
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more back-end info. You can use LINQ on the DataGridView datasource and by this choose required row, than delete easily.